# Low pass filter with apply function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, lowpass-filter

I have a question.how can I write the code.

I want to create an image interface. The class filter should apply a low-pass filter to a given image and should be derived from an abstract base class Image. The filter class holds a 1D array with 3 elements which are used as the filter kernel for 1D filter operation. However, the apply_1D method is applied two times and it stores the intermediate result in a transposed image ( with rows and columns interchanged). I should use value 0 if values outside my image need to be accessed and the image is stored row-major, all pixels of the first row, then all pixels of the second row, and another thing it is required to pair a row and column, or a pair of height and width in order ( row first, then column).

| input image |  |
| --- | --- |
| First rows | 0, 0, 0,0, 0 |
| Second row | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| third row | 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 |
| fourth row | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| fifth row | 0, 0,0 ,0, 0 |

the output image is :

| input image |  |
| --- | --- |
| First rows | 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 |
| Second row | 0 , 0.0625 , 0.125 , 0.0625 , 0 |
| third row | 0 , 0.125 , 0.25 , 0.125, 0 |
| fourth row | 0 , 0.625 , 0.125 , 0.0625 , 0 |
| fifth row | 0 , 0 ,0 , 0, 0 |

```
import os

class Filter:
    kernel = [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]

    def apply(self, img: InterfaceImage) -> InterfaceImage:
        return self._apply_1d(self._apply_1d(img))

    def _apply_1d(self, in_img: InterfaceImage) -> InterfaceImage:
        new_height = in_img.width
        new_width = in_img.height
        out_transposed = Image(new_height, new_width, [0] * new_height * new_width)
        
        height = in_img.height
        width = in_img.width

        for row in range(height):
            for col in range(width):
                filtered = (
                    Filter.kernel[0] * in_img.get(row, col - 1)
                    + Filter.kernel[1] * in_img.get(row, col)
                    + Filter.kernel[2] * in_img.get(row, col + 1)
                )
                # HINT: The set method always takes row first, column second. It is called with 
                #       'col, row' below because 'out_transposed' is a transposed image.
                out_transposed.set(col, row, filtered)

        return out_transposed

def to_string(image: InterfaceImage) -> str:
    result = ""
    for row in range(image.height):
        for col in range(image.width):
            result += "{:.5f}  ".format(image.get(row, col))
        result += "\n"
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    height_and_width = input()
    height, width = (int(item) for item in height_and_width.split())
    
    data = []
    
    for _ in range(height):
        for value in input().split():
            data.append(float(value))

    
    filter = Filter()

    image = Image(height=height, width=width, data=data)
    filtered_image = filter.apply(image)

    result = to_string(filtered_image)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Python being an interpreted language the numerical computations will be very slow. You may want to use numpy for math ops. Why cant you use OpenCV ?